# Questions about Viewports and large image navigation

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I'm working on a project using JavaScript and the basic UI we want to be a very large background image, and when you select the navigation menu items it propels you to a section on that large image.

I've tried finding documentation on Viewports and trying to figure out how Map applications function but have had very very minimal success.

It would basically be a Google map without the user being able to slide it.  How in the world would I begin to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `background-image` property in CSS and use javascript to change the `background-position`.

Comment: Thank you!  Forgive my ignorance.